# Why can't jQuery get data from $_POST['order_number'] if the number starts with "000"?

Tags: php, jquery

Why can't I transfer a variable from one PHP file to another via `$_POST['order_number']`? I have this:

```
<script>
  function Remove(order_number)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: 'order_number='+order_number,
       url: "2_remove.php",
       cache: false,

     });
 }
</script>
```

And this is `2_remove.php`:

```
<?
// Config file!
include "config.php";

//include('parser.php');

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusr, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//param-vars

$order_number=$_POST['order_number'];

//CHANGE STATUS

$conn->query("DELETE FROM 2dopuzzler where ordernum = $order_number");
?>
```

It's ok if `$_POST['order_number']` is `1234`. *But*(!) if it is like `000123`, it does nothing! Why? I have to add an extra `1` or remove `000`... That's not ok.

Comment: You don't say what the actual problem is, or what you have tried to do to solve this. "It does nothing" is not an error report. It is a complaint. Anyway, you should look hard at what the ajax call is doing with regards to the data, and what PHP does when it gets the data and when it uses it in a query. This is looking like data is being coerced to an integer from a String but only in some cases. This should be easy to debug.

Comment: I need to know why i can't have a varible starting with 000. And how I can't have it like unchanged.

Comment: Like I said, you need to understand what sort of data you are using to construct the query. But it is unclear what error you are actually running into.

Comment: There's no reason you can't have a variable contain a value starting with 000 (or rather, even if it was casting to an integer it would still produce '1234', not 'nothing'), so something else must be going wrong and you need to debug it. First steps, console.log(order_number) from within Remove() and var_dump $_POST and see what values you get, this might give you some insight as to where (and therefore why) the value is being lost.

Comment: The varible cant' have 000 at the beging OR letters [Aa-Zz] So I add 1, e.g. now it's 1000123. It's ok. Or it it is Z000123. It's broken. So I have to add an exta digit... It must be like 1Z000123. Isn't that crazy? )

Comment: `DELETE FROM 2dopuzzler where ordernum = $order_number` < no `'` marks around `$order_number` means it's being treated as an Integer, hence no leading zeroes so it won't match order *0001234* (assuming `ordernum` is something like `VARCHAR`) and nothing will be deleted. You should use a prepared statement with a parameterised query anyway.

Comment: I can have any varible if i do like 2_remove.php?order_number=000123. But i can't get 000123 from script which is in another php.

Comment: What's the datatype of the `ordernum` column anyway? Assuming it's not an auto-incremented integer as a primary key.

Comment: Don't write your queries like this.  Look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  if you do this you will get hacked.

Comment: NO, it's not  auto-incremented integer as a primary key! How d^W... It's text. Yes, it's just text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use intval() http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php for solve this and to avoid mysql injection 
$order_number=intval($_POST['order_number']);

Also note.
Using data from request directly in mysql query is potential backdore. 
It's real dangerous.

It's enought to use intval in examle above.

But if you works with string, better to use mysqli_real_escape_string() http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: It's not a web/online smth. It's just a local kinda browser app. Anyway, thank you )

Answer (score 0):

if (as you said) `order_number` is not an int, you need to put it in ticks.

change `$conn->query("DELETE FROM 2dopuzzler where ordernum = $order_number");`

to `$conn->query("DELETE FROM 2dopuzzler where ordernum = '".$order_number."'");`